# Record allowing members implementing any interface which extends another

Tags: typescript

This is my current code:

```js
interface hasFoo {
  foo: string;
}

interface hasBar extends hasFoo {
  bar: string;
}

interface hasBaz extends hasFoo {
  baz: string;
}

const myRecord: Record<string, hasFoo> = {
  "a": {
    foo: "hello",
    bar: "world",
  },
  "b": {
    foo: "goodbye",
    baz: "my lover",
  },
  "c": {
    foo: "periwinkle",
  },
}
```

However, this doesn't work (`'bar' does not exist in type 'hasFoo'`). I could do `Record<string, hasFoo | hasBar | hasBaz>`, but that would quickly get unwieldy if I add more interfaces which extend `hasFoo`. Instead, I want something like `Record<string, extends hasFoo>`. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create `hasFoo` and compiler gives error as `bar` or `baz` is not defined in `hasFoo`. But, as you can see type casting actually works as expected.

```
const myRecord: Record<string, hasFoo> = {
  "a": {
    foo: "hello",
    bar: "world",
  } as hasBar,
  "b": {
    foo: "goodbye",
    baz: "my lover",
  } as hasBaz,
  "c": {
    foo: "periwinkle",
  },
}
```

or

```
const myRecord: Record<string, hasFoo> = {
  "a": {
    foo: "hello",
    bar: "world",
  } ,
  "b": {
    foo: "goodbye",
    baz: "my lover",
  } ,
  "c": {
    foo: "periwinkle",
  },
} as Record<string, hasFoo>
```

Comment: Yes I am using this workaround now but I would like to know if there is a way of defining a more loose type for the `Record`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
const myRecord: Record<string, Record<string,string> & hasFoo> = {
  "a": {
    foo: "hello",
    bar: "world",
  },
  "b": {
    foo: "goodbye",
    baz: "my lover",
  },
  "c": {
    foo: "periwinkle",
  },
}
```

which will be less maintenance than

```
const myRecord2: Record<string, hasBar | hasBaz | hasFoo> = {
  "a": {
    foo: "hello",
    bar: "world",
  },
  "b": {
    foo: "goodbye",
    baz: "my lover",
  },
  "c": {
    foo: "periwinkle",
  },
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=42&ssc=2&pln=30&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAFghgZwGIHsVQLxQN4CgpQBmaAXFAsAE4CWAdgOYDcuAvrrqJLIgEJyWYC8ZGgIAyHPigAjfmQo0GzNh3DRhfAF6DhqdBLwFZm+VTpNW7dgGMUtClAC2IAEoRblACZk3HzwB4FcwAaKF8UL0CzBmCghgA+KAldNESsQygAIjhMsgyCYhQyTJgIABsylEzgqSM5LIB3CLLPaqkWGoJM6VzJAgLSLPo0T2kQCDb+mTgTLOcoSoA3CEpJqA6pTOte-KJBzMgaBroAazKJzvWalVxbe2AnV3cIzwAmH2fIuPpQjX4oAA+3AQWkBwL0aT6WRyeVqeyKWVKFSqlzqlGKTUoLTWGy6PVhU0KxWGKFG4zWdVmmXmSxWOMuWx2cKJWUO1GOtDOF3a1yAA)

Comment: This allows adding a property to the `Record` such as `"d": { foo: "good", boo: "ghost" }`, but I want to only be able to add properties which conform to `hasFoo` or any  interface which extends `hasFoo`.

Comment: Then you have to go with the union, extends doesn't allow you to add properties that don't exist on the type your extending from what I could find. Basically any type that satisifes the definition of hasFoo is considered to match it according to typescript. If you want to only use interfaces which extend it you have to list them to omit other matching types.